# Expand Collapse not working in Visual Studio Code 1.22.1 Version

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Expand and collapse for the code block is not working. I tried to the control <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and also changed the user settings to `"editor.wordWrap": "on"`.

Is is the correct way to do, it was working earlier without any setting but after the update I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 14):

This could be an issue with the [syntax aware folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_syntax-aware-folding) introduced in the March 2018 update. Does this setting suggested in the release notes help?

```json
"editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
```

Comment: I have added that property in my user settings still no luck.